# How to install and run Deployer on Windows

Tags: php, php-deployer

I want to install Deployer on Windows. I have followed below steps:

- Run command in cmd: D:\composer require deployer/deployer:~3.0
- Then D:\php vendor/bin/dep

When I run above command it shows me below thing:

> dir=$(d=${0%[/\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../deployer/deployer/bin" && pwd)

```
# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
    # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
    # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
    # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
    if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
    fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/dep" "$@"
```

Also when I tried to run 'dep' command D:>dep self-update, it shows me this error:

> 'dep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Now what should I do to make and run deployer script? Please tell me the further steps.

Comment: use "deployer.phar" instead of "dep". You may not need to specify the path.

Answer (score 4):

Install Deployer globally

```
composer global require deployer/deployer
```

Add the Composer path to windows environment variables

```
%AppData%\Composer\vendor\bin
```

Open new terminal and run the `dep` command

Comment: This works on my Windows 10.
Make sure you already installed composer.

Answer (score 0):

Open or navigate to the project directory in command prompt then Use `vendor/bin/dep` to use `dep` in windows

Answer (score 0):

Calling `"vendor/bin/dep"` works for me.

Don't run the command through php